# Can't install windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I've written a windows service, but when I installed it there was a system.security.securityexception. I think it is because I imported a function from user32.dll, but I don't know.
Can anyone help me?

Edit:

Installlog:

Sorry for the language.

Während der Installationsphase ist eine Ausnahme aufgetreten.
System.Security.SecurityException: Die Quelle wurde nicht gefunden, aber einige oder alle Ereignisprotokolle konnten nicht durchsucht werden. Protokolle, auf die kein Zugriff möglich war: Security.

Comment: Can you post the install log file? And the stack trace indicating to you that it was a `System.Security.SecurityException`? Your code wouldn't hurt, either. I have a few guesses, but at this point, that's all they are.

Comment: Does this exception happen when installing the service or after a successful installation when the service tries to start?

Comment: @mOsa The Exception happens during the installation with installutil

Comment: Are you an administrator on your machine ?

Comment: Yes, I'm an admin. I'm the only user.

Comment: If it's Windows 7 you must run the command line as admin, otherwise it won't "catch". We still need to see full error though, like Cody asked above.

Comment: Translation of the exception text: `During installation, an exception has occurred. System.Security.SecurityException: The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched. Protocols to which access was not possible: Security`

Comment: Thanks, Shadow Wizard, that solved my Problem. I didn't run it as administrator.

Comment: @eagle999 cheers, I've added this as Answer so you can accept. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's Windows 7 or Vista you must run the command line as admin, otherwise it won't "catch".

To do that, click the Windows button or start "Orb", type "cmd" then instead of hitting the Enter key, hit CTRL+SHIFT+Enter key and confirm the dialog.